# Broken S4 screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, touchscreen

I broke my S4 screen while celebrating  my team scoring! I looked up the local phone shops but they are too expensive. Anyone know what I should do? Maybe buy a screen off eBay? I have been told S4's are a nightmare to fix yourself, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Is your whole screen assembly not working or did the screen glass just fracture?

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Samsung+Galaxy+S4+Display+Assembly+Replacement/16540

A quick google search. Replacing the whole assembly is indeed some work.

If just the glass is broken you may remove the broken glass with a heating and replace it with a new one with a relatively low price to it.

I've never performed either of it, but both procedures do look risky. There are some good YouTube videos about the glass replacement. But as always you could render your phone unusable.

Comment: It still works I am replying to you using it. It's just the glass it has a lot of cracks in it. I fixed my old iPhone myself but I have heard s4's are on an other level 9f difficulty. I am going to give it a go. No way am I paying £85 to fix it. That's the same price I bought the phone for!

Comment: @PaulLaing I fixed an S4 screen, however I replaced the entire display assemble (LCD included). It wasn't very difficult.

Comment: @PaulLaing You can get an OEM LCD+Digitizer on Ebay for $68: http://www.ebay.com/itm/OEM-Samsung-Galaxy-S4-IV-i9500-LCD-Display-Touch-Digitizer-Screen-Assembly-Black-/201258885398?hash=item2edbf6e116:g:hWkAAOSw42JWDbi8